# Pure CSS Modal (Not Bootstrap) inside PHP While Loop

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a pure css based modal as I am not using bootstrap on a project for some reason. The modal should open when a link is clicked inside the records fetched via while loop. Now the problem is that I want to fetch and display the record as per that particular record for which the modal is created as different records have different data of course but I am not getting an idea on how to do it. Here are my codes.

```
<?php while($rm = $rooms->fetch()){ ?>
  <tr>
    <td class="text-left"><?php echo $rm['rm_name']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $rm['rm_max_children']; ?></td>
    <td><a href="#modal-one" class="modelView" data-id="<?php echo $rm['rm_id'];?>">View</a></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
<?php } ?>
<div class="modal" id="modal-one" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h2>Facilities</h2>
      <a href="#" class="btn-close" aria-hidden="true">×</a>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <div class="modelContent">Different record as per id to be displayed here by field <?php echo $rm['rm_facilities']; ?></div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <a href="#" class="btn">Close</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I searched a few similar questions but all were related to bootstrap. I also tried breaking them out of the bootstrap and trying it on mine but they did not seem to work.

Comment: I don't understand what you want ? you want the CSS of the MODAL or how show the content in this modal from while loop ?

Comment: I want how to show the content in this model from while loop..

Comment: what's the response you'll get onclick to show modal? JSON or HTML ?

Comment: Nothing right now. Whatever I tried gave undefined error so I deleted those codes.

Answer (score 0):

There're two ideas here,

1. **first**: use **data- notations**. static example is

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.btn-close').click(function(e) {
    $('.modal').hide();
  });

  // hide modal by default
  $('.modal').hide();

  $('.modelView').click(function(e) {
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    var name = $(this).data('name');
    var children = $(this).data('children');
    var description = $(this).data('description');

    $('#RoomId').text(id);
    $('#RoomName').text(name);
    $('#RoomChildren').text(children);
    $('#RoomDescription').text(description);

    // show modal
    $('.modal').show();
  });
});
```

```html
<table border="1" style="width: 100%;">
  <thead>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Children</th>
    <th></th>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-left">Room 1</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td><a href="#modal-one" class="modelView" data-id="1" data-name="Room 1" data-description="room 1 description room 1 description room 1 description" data-children="4">View</a></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-left">Room2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td><a href="#modal-one" class="modelView" data-id="2" data-name="Room 2" data-description="room 2 description room 2 description room 2 description" data-children="3">View</a></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>


<div class="modal" id="RoomDeatilModal" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h2>Facilities</h2>
      <a href="#" class="btn-close" aria-hidden="true">×</a>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <div class="modelContent">
        <div>
          <b>Room Id:</b>
          <span id="RoomId"></span>
        </div>
        <div>
          <b>Room Name:</b>
          <span id="RoomName"></span>
        </div>
        <div>
          <b>Children:</b>
          <span id="RoomChildren"></span>
        </div>
        <div>
          <b>Room Description:</b>
          <span id="RoomDescription"></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <a href="#" class="btn">Close</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

2. Second: send **AJAX request** with ID and get data then display it in modal

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.btn-close').click(function(e) {
    $('.modal').hide();
  });

  // hide modal by default
  $('.modal').hide();

  $('.modelView').click(function(e) {
    var id = $(this).data('id');

    //$.get('/api/Rooms/getById/' + id, function(response) { // send ajax with this line
    var response = { id: 1, name: 'room 1', children: 4, description: 'description room 1'}; // remove this line after call ajax .. this is example of ajax response
      $('#RoomId').text(response.id);
      $('#RoomName').text(response.name);
      $('#RoomChildren').text(response.children);
      $('#RoomDescription').text(response.description);

      // show modal
      $('.modal').show();
    //});

  });

});
```

```html
<table border="1" style="width: 100%;">
  <thead>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Children</th>
    <th></th>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-left">Room 1</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td><a href="#modal-one" class="modelView" data-id="1">View</a></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>


<div class="modal" id="RoomDeatilModal" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h2>Facilities</h2>
      <a href="#" class="btn-close" aria-hidden="true">×</a>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <div class="modelContent">
        <div>
          <b>Room Id:</b>
          <span id="RoomId"></span>
        </div>
        <div>
          <b>Room Name:</b>
          <span id="RoomName"></span>
        </div>
        <div>
          <b>Children:</b>
          <span id="RoomChildren"></span>
        </div>
        <div>
          <b>Room Description:</b>
          <span id="RoomDescription"></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <a href="#" class="btn">Close</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```